# Grub Loader very slow

Tags: linux, ubuntu

My GRUB loader is taking a very long time to load. I've ran these commands and these are the outputs.

```
$ systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 3min 34.735s (firmware) + 5.445s (loader) + 50.842s (kernel) + 44.191s (userspace) = 5min 15.214s
graphical.target reached after 43.954s in userspace

$ systemd-analyze blame
```

https://pastebin.com/xJvkYEfX

```
$ sudo journalctl --boot
```

https://pastebin.com/Vef6dCTT

From the `sudo journalctl --boot` command. I see there are some problems with startup not sure how to fix them.